# Why so many gettimeofday calls?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Why does the PHP/Apache combo do so many `gettimeofday` syscalls? Even though the're quick every call is a call which should be accounted for.

Just a quick `strace -c -p [apache2 process id]`, gives the following:

```
Process 22294 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 98.52    0.010000          51       196           poll
  1.48    0.000150           0     20752           gettimeofday
  0.00    0.000000           0        94         7 read
  0.00    0.000000           0        48           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        96        32 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        75           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           chdir
  0.00    0.000000           0       766           time
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           chmod
  0.00    0.000000           0        56        10 access
```

Those 20K calls worry me. Anyone care to shed some light on this?

Comment: Java is even worse...

Comment: What is your program doing?

Comment: Just serving up various PHP scripts. Nothing special. There are some date/time/mktime related function calls, but not 20K per sec.. ;)

Comment: I cannot answer the "why" but are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266813/anyone-can-understand-how-gettimeofday-works and https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-General_System_Tuning-gettimeofday_speedup.html ? The syscall typically would be mapped to user space code ("vsyscall") so overhead would be reduced significantly.

Comment: The count shouldn't worry you. Poll has only 200 calls, but it uses over 98% of the time. You can switch to the normal strace output, then you'll see what apache is doing (will slow it down alot tho).

Comment: I wasnt aware of the redhat page @syneticon-dj, thanks for that

Comment: The polling done by apache seems logical since its waiting for requests... that doesnt worry me as much...

since then i've done some further testing and found alot of gettimeofday calls even when doing CLI php scripts... must be purely PHP somewhere (https://twitter.com/langemeijer mentioned APC might be a culprit with its LRU caching?)

Comment: Related: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/08/system-calls-are-much-slower-on-ec2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gettimeofday is mostly called by Apache to log entries in debug-files. Also some modules use gettimeofday. So nothing to worry about.

EDIT:
I did some php source code digging and came up with the following results:
Most time related php functions will use the system time. Since they use the system time, gettimeofday will be called a lot so if you want to reducte the calls, reducte your time related functions.

I have to remark though that other functions also make gettimeofday-calls. For example if you use php_session_start, this will (sometimes, depening on a few parameters like if a new session,...) make a call to php_combined_lcg which will make in his turn a call to lcg_seed if there is no seed value set to get a pseudo random number. And lcg_seed will make a gettimeofday call. Keep this in mind.

Comment: But what if my CLI php script also does _alot_ of gettimeofday calls? is there something wrong with my php? (does i.e. date() or mktime() use those functions if i dont provide a timestamp as a param?)

Comment: Searched a bit and edited my answer

Comment: Thanks... I guess i just have to live with all those calls. :)

Comment: If you have `xdebug` installed, it can also be a byproduct of it.

Answer (score 1):

Every process that requires a timestamp calls gettimeofday, so it is difficult to know whether it is normal or not.

For example, It can be a module that creates a log, a module that checks the time... 
In fact, in your case, to know why there are so many gettimeofday, disable apache modules that could be responsible for calling gettimeofday. There are maybe too many writes to numerous log files located in different folders.

- Disable the usual suspects like mod_log_debug or mod_status
- Reload configuration of Apache
- strace

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that having the php module, xdebug, enabled causes strace to report several `gettimeofday` calls.